# Why does this Raspberry Pi GPIO event run twice if I remove the print statement?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I run this script when the Raspberry Pi boots. When I press the key (GPIO 19) the `interrupt` function gets called.

If I *remove* the `print("BUTTON PRESSED")` statement on line 10, the `interrupt` function seems to be called twice in a row for a single button press.

Any idea why this is the case?

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def interrupt(channel):
    print("BUTTON PRESSED")
    p = subprocess.Popen(['node', '/btn.js', str(channel)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.stdout.read()
    print(out)

GPIO.add_event_detect(19, GPIO.FALLING, callback=interrupt, bouncetime=1000)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except:  
    print("Exit GPIO Listener..")
finally
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the debounce timeout?

Comment: it was originally set to 200 i thought having a longer bounce would reduce noise/accidental double clicks but I may be misunderstanding the parameter